# What is basic use of "be to"

Tags: be

I would like to know what is the basic use of "be to" mainly in reference to the present or future. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
 like:

> 1. How is this to be avoided?
> 2. You are to come tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. One basic use of the phrase would *be* to reference the present or future, often with *would* placed in front of *to be*. If you can supply a sample sentence, editing it into your question can focus the discussion more helpfully.

Comment: I think what you have is a set of words that appear together, but are really part of separate phrases. For example, in the first, the word "is" links "this to "to be avoided". In the second, the word "are" relates "you" to the phrase "to come", and "tomorrow" provides further information to "come". There isn't really a proper (semantic) "be to" phrase in those examples - the words just happened to appear together, just like the words "here so" in your question's first sentence.

Comment: @Lawrence Many grammars and dictionaries would not agree with you (although I do*ish*). It's often taught as a type of modal construction - where *modal* just means having to do with modality. Here's a link to [a page on *to be to*](http://www.grammaring.com/be-to-infinitive)

Comment: @Lawrence These types of usage are interesting because there is a small but significant number of grammarians who argue that the infinitival word *to* is actually a non-finite modal verb. These usages seem to support this idea.

Comment: The construction is used to convey deontic modality or futurity.

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks for your comments. I can see the point you make about the alternate perspective (very interesting), and fully agree with the point about futurity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure *to be* + *to infinitive* would be used as follows:

> You are to come tomorrow

This can be elliptic for:

> You are (ordered/expected/supposed) to come tomorrow.

Unfortunately, dictionaries don't give such explanations yet. In some cases you have to find a verb form that fits in.

Comment: @waqt Your question is currently closed. I think it is a good question, but it needs a lot more details. For example, you could add what you know about the construction (for example, if you know that Palmer said something about it) and where you have seen it, or what you *think* it means. If you do this, I fairly confident that the question will be reopened.